# Datagridview link column - add text to rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to add column to Datagrid, and display text "View details" in each row, underlined as hyperlink. I tried add link column and using Text property & .UseColumnTextForLinkValue to True, but not working for me:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Call AddLinkColumn()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddLinkColumn()

        Dim links As New DataGridViewLinkColumn()
        With links

            .Text = "View details"
            .UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
            .HeaderText = "Address"

            .ActiveLinkColor = Color.White
            .LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault
            .LinkColor = Color.Blue
            .TrackVisitedState = True
            .VisitedLinkColor = Color.YellowGreen
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(links)
    End Sub

End Class
```

What am I doing wrong, or is there any other option to display text in rows ? Click on text will open linked paths for Datagrid records on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with code, when I start typing in Datagrid, link text appears in cells. It just doesn't when datagrid is empty, that's all. Sorry for posting, I didn't knew that.